# How to handle postgresql too many connection with jNDi datasource

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

Hi i have tested my spring-hibernate app with Jmeter for testing the performance of the app.So i  used max thread of 1000 connection the application via calling restful web services.
But when i run the application i shows too many connections error.How do i overcome these issue.
I read HIKARICP is alternative and it is fast.should i migrate to hikaricp?

datasource configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:jboss/datasources/DFSAppDS</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

jndi mapping in standalone.xml file

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DFSAppDS" pool-name="DFSAppDSPool">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dfs</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>2000</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Comment: "*How do i overcome these issue*" - by reducing the value for `max-pool-size` to a reasonable value. 2000 is **way**, way too much. Why do you think you need that many? On really fast, high-end hardware you could maybe go up to 500. A value 50 to 100 is **much** more sensible.

Comment: i thought increasing max connection value will solve my problem. But i was wrong.

Comment: Increasing `max_connections` to at least 2003 will get rid of the *symptom* (after a database restart), but the *problem* is better tackled by reducing `max-pool-size`.

Comment: Now i changed to min 50 and max 1000 , so does it will handle 1000+ at a time?